# Order send to email rather than checking out

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am using WordPress woo commerce on my website. I want my orders sent to email rather than checking out to paypal. I am selling medicine and paypal doesn't allow their services for websites that are dealing with medicine. So I want my orders straight to my email and where I can contact users.

I want to know Is it possible to do it with woocommerce?
Is there any plugin which can do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `WooCommerce->Settings->Checkout`, disable all payment options except for "Cash on Delivery".

Then change the `title` to something like "Pay by Phone" and in the `Description` and `Instructions` fields something like "Call 123-456-7890 to complete your order." then the order will be placed, but they have to call to complete payment.

Or you can change the wording to indicate that you'll call them. Just make sure that the phone number field is required if you take that route.

Comment: This is close to what I want Is there any plugin which can email contact and order details to me?

Comment: As soon as the order is submitted, if you've set up the email settings in `Woocommerce->Settings->Emails`, then an email will be sent to the person whose email address you entered in the `New Order` notification section. I just tried it out on my setup. I pretended to be a user and I received an email, as well as the admin of the store whose email address is in that field received an email with the customer details from the checkout form.